# datasets: xml or mysql faster?

Tags: mysql, xml, database, dataset

I'm using the stackoverflow dataset, I would like to know if I should convert the dataset from xml to mysql to improve the retrieval performances and work more efficiently.

If it is better to convert to mysql, can you suggest conversion tools (I'm on a mac)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases are designed and optimized for data storage, query and retrieval.

As a consequence they perform almost always better as any text files that need to be parsed.

But you must also evaluate whether performance matters for you in this case at all?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990851/Stackoverflow-data-in-MySQL

BTW: Absolutely, having it in MySQL format is faster for data management.